# No internet access unless connecting through VPN/proxy - How can this be done?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, proxy

At work, our computers are set up so that you can't access the internet unless you authenticate with an http proxy that is configured using wpad.

I want to have something similar for my home network for content blocking, etc.

How can I achieve something like this?

I have a linksys wrt54gL router with ddwrt installed on it, and have 5-6 devices connected through wiree, powerline ethernet, and wireless connections.

Comment: What type of content are you trying to block? Block certain ports, hostnames, services? Setting a proxy is fairly straight forward (search for "Squid"); however, you want to pick the right tool for the right problem.

Comment: How much are you trying to lock it down? Shoving everything on your network through your proxy is easy - you control the infrastructure after all. Making sure all the client systems only ever use your proxies, no matter where they are, is a whole 'nother problem - for that, you need very strict control and management over the client devices.

Comment: i want a situation similar to work, where accessing the internet through the router is not possible without valid credentials, regardless of whether or not you know the password to the wireless/have physical access to the network

Answer (score 0):

For Internet Explorer, you can use "Content Advisor" to do internet content blocking to a certain level. Please refer the below link for more information:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361897.aspx

For Google Chrome, you can use "Mature content filter" plugins from store to achieve internet content blocking.

But please note that, these settings may not be useful as like your office environment security settings, but to a certain level.